# How to calculate this cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X = \mathbb{P}^{3}$ and $C \subset X$ an irreducible smooth curve. Let $I_{C}$ be the ideal sheaf of $C$.

> I am trying to calculate the following cohomology: $$H^{i}(X, \Omega_{X}^{1} \otimes \bigwedge^{i+1}T_{X} \otimes S^{i}(\mathcal{F}) \otimes I_{C}(m))$$ with $i = 1, 2$ and   $0 < m \leq 2$,  where:
>
> 1) $\mathcal{F}$ is a locally free sheaf of $\text{rank}$ one. More precisely, in my case, it is: $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{O}_{X}(c + d)$  and $S^{i}(\mathcal{F})$ is the $\text{i-th}$ symmetric power of $\mathcal{F}$.
>
> 2) $I_{C}$ is the ideal sheaf of $C$.
>
> **My objective is**: $H^{i}(X, \Omega_{X}^{1} \otimes \bigwedge^{i+1}T_{X} \otimes S^{i}(\mathcal{F}) \otimes I_{C}(m)) = 0$ with $i = 1, 2$

**What i'm trying to do**: For a question asked here in the forum:  (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/715318/emanuell), Holomorphic Vector Bundle and Non-Degenerate Pairing, I have the following isomorphisms:

a) For $i = 1$. $$\bigwedge^{2}T_{X} \simeq \Omega_{X}^{1}(4)$$

b) For $i = 2$ $$\bigwedge^{3}T_{X} \simeq \mathcal{O}_{X}(4)$$

My problem now is the $S^{i}(\mathcal{F})$. I don't know what is: $\bigwedge^{i+1}T_{X} \otimes S^{i}(\mathcal{F})$ (*)

After understanding this (*), I will try to use the following tools: **Mumford's Regularity Theorem**, because:

i) **Bott's formula** tells us that **$\Omega_{X}^{1}$ is 2-regular** .

ii) The **corollary 2.1** of the article: **Vanishing Theorems, A Theorem Of  Severi and the equations defining projective variety**, that says about the aforementioned regularity for an ideal sheaf.

Thank you  and a lot from now, any help.

Comment: $S^i(\mathcal{F}) = \mathcal{F}^{\otimes i} = \mathcal{O}_X(i(c+d))$ since $\mathcal{F}$ is a line bundle, and you can use the Euler sequence to understand the exterior powers of the tangent bundle.

Comment: @AlanMuniz. Thank you.