# About Castelnuovo-Mumford Regularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

I asked the following question here in our forum: ([How to calculate this cohomology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3399038) )

> **Proposition** (1): Let $\mathcal{F}$ be  be coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ and let $E$ be a locally free sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^{n}$. If $\mathcal{F}$ is $m$-regular and $E$ is $\ell$-regular, then $\mathcal{F} \otimes E$ is (m + $\ell$)-regular.
>
> **Proposition** (2): If $E$ is an $m$-regular locally free sheaf, then $\bigwedge^{p}E$ is $(pm)$-regular.
>
> **Proposition** (3): Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ be an irreducible (but possibly singular) reduced curve of degree $d$. Assume that $C$ is non-degenerate, i.e, that it doesn't lie in any hyperplane. Then $C$ is $(d + 2 - n)$-regular.
>
> **Serre Duality** : $H^{q}(X, E)^{'} \simeq H^{n-q}(X, E^{*} \otimes \omega_{X})$
>
> **Vector bundle isomorphism** : $\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{p *} \simeq \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{n-p} \otimes \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{n *}$

Using the above tools together with a projection formula, I think I answered the question. I also think it can be generalized.

Using the answer to this question (mathoverflow.net/questions/66980/) and using the above mentioned tools once again, I get: $$H^{1}(\mathbb{P}^{3}, \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}^{2} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(a) \otimes I_{C}^{\otimes 2})$$

We have:

I) $\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}^{1}$ is $2$-regular (Bott's Formula). Then, by **proposition (2)**,  $\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}^{2}$ is $4$-regular.

II) $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(a)$ is $(-a)$-regular

III) By **proposition (3)**, assuming the non-degenerate curve, we have : $I_{C}$ is $(\text{deg}(C) + 2 - 3) = (\text{deg}(C) - 1)$-regular.

**My doubt is**:  Can I use **proposition (1)** to conclude that:  $(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}^{2} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(a) \otimes I_{C}^{\otimes 2})$ is $(4 + (-a) + 2(\text{deg}(C) - 1))$-regular?

References are:

[1] Robert Lazarsfeld. Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I.

[2] Christian Okonek. Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As $\Omega_X^p$ is locally free for any $p$ and any smooth scheme $X$, the whole problem comes down to figuring out whether $I_C^{\otimes 2}$ is $2\deg(C)-2$ regular. This is true as per lemma 1.5 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110184.pdf) but I wouldn't be surprised if there were an easier argument.

Comment: @KReiser. Thank you very much for your suggestion.